# How do I get C function calls which has underscore in it using Regular expression in Python?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, parsing

I am writing a Python script for parsing C function calls in a function definition. The function name may have one or more underscore in it. Below is the sample code:-

```
import re

line = "int main(){\n    func();\n    func_1();\n    func_call();\n}"

p = re.compile('\n\s*([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*)\(', re.MULTILINE)
print "Regex 1:-\t{}".format(re.findall(p, line))

p = re.compile('\n\s*(\w+)\(', re.MULTILINE)
print "Regex 2:-\t{}".format(re.findall(p, line))
```

Output:-

```
Regex 1:-   ['func', 'func_1']
Regex 2:-   ['func', 'func_1']
```

Apparently, both regular expression could get function call "func_call". Why both the regular expressions could not capture "func_call()"? How do I modify the regular expression such that it parses "func_call()"?

Comment: [Can't reproduce](https://ideone.com/o9fEYV). Also, why are you passing `re.MULTILINE`?

Comment: I've been running the code in "https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_python_online.php " and I was able to run it without any problem. This code runs on Python 2.7. Option re.Multiline is used here since the string has newlines in it.

Comment: Please read https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.M. `re.MULTILINE` only affects what `^` and `$` do, and your regex doesn't contain `^` or `$`.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I figured out that there was some problem with ""tutorialspoint.com/execute_python_online.php" and not the script. Probably, I should not run scripts on this website.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because apparently tutorialspoint.com strips out `call(` from your source code before it even runs.

If you change your code to just

```
line = "int main(){\n    func();\n    func_1();\n    func_call();\n}"
print "[" + line + "]"
```

You can see the output is

```
$python main.py
[int main(){
    func();
    func_1();
    func_);
}]
```

Even better/worse, you [can do this](http://tpcg.io/d4B89z):

```
call(
prcall(int "Hello, call(world!"call(
```

It will output `Hello, world!` as if the code had been

```
print "Hello, world!"
```

all along.

If you change the name in your original code to `func_cxall`, it also works. It is only the specific five-character sequence `call(` that is being removed.